# Xcode - Where to configure this icon picture

Tags: xcode

Where to configure this icon picture next to the Scheme in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: You should find the app icon in the Assets.xcassets folder.  Did you create the icons for this app?  Do you have Sketch or Figma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/) for your application, you can set or change it in `Assets.xcassets`. You can find your app icon assets under `project -> Target -> General -> App icons and images`

[image]

If you click on arrow sign (➜) then you directly jump to App Icon assets.

Comment: there are Appicon in my project, that was why it has no effect after changing the icon photo